# How to Export Environment Variable From Script in PHP Docker Entrypoint

Tags: php, docker

I have a script that grabs variables and export it as environment variable. And I also have PHP-based docker for my web application. I tried to execute the script in the `docker-php-entrypoint` but the environment variable is not loaded.

The Dockerfile is like below.

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

COPY docker-php-entrypoint /usr/local/bin/
COPY load_parameter_store.sh /opt/
COPY src/ /var/www/html/
```

This is the `docker-php-entrypoint` content. It runs a script `load_parameter_store.sh`.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

/opt/load_parameter_store.sh

# first arg is `-f` or `--some-option`
if [ "${1#-}" != "$1" ]; then
    set -- php "$@"
fi

exec "$@"
```

And this is the script itself

```
EXPORT_STATEMENT='export MY_VARIABLE=FooBar' #Will be loaded from AWS SSM Parameter Store

eval $EXPORT_STATEMENT
```

I have a PHP web script that shows the environment variable.

```
<?php

$var = $_ENV['MY_VARIABLE'];
echo "Hello World {$var}";
```

The end goal is that I would like the PHP shows `Hello World FooBar` but what I get is just `Hello World`. It means that the variable is not loaded.

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the special [shell `.` command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot) to run the script that sets the environment variables:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# the `.` at the start of this line is required
. /opt/load_parameter_store.sh

# double check: you will not see a value here without the `.`
echo "MY_VARIABLE is '$MY_VARIABLE'"
```

Some shells have an identical command named `source`, but it's not part of the POSIX standard, and it won't work on the `/bin/sh` included in an Alpine base image.

If you don't use `.` then the `load_parameter_store.sh` script will run as a subprocess in a new shell; anything that gets `export`ed there will be limited to that script's shell environment, and it will got lost when the script completes.

Comment: Oh yes, that's correct. I tried `source` initially but it returned error. Thanks a lot!